# How to replace one row in a list of matrices in r ?

Tags: r, matrix

Suppose I have some list *li* of matrices. For instance,

```
 m1=matrix(1:9,nrow=3,byrow=T)
 m2=matrix(1:16,nrow=4,byrow=T)
 m3=matrix(1:25,nrow=5,byrow=T)
 li=list(m1,m2,m3).
```

And I want to replace the first row in each matrix by the sequence of consequtive numbers 100 of the appropiate length. On single matrix, this operation has the form:

```
m1[1,]=rep(100,ncol(m1))
```

or alternatively

```
li[[1]][1,]=rep(100,ncol(li[[1]])).
```

I will obtain the desired matrix:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  100  100  100
[2,]    4    5    6
[3,]    7    8    9
```

But if I try to repeat the above procedure on the list *li* of matrices, i.e.,

```
li.prim=lapply(1:3,function(x)li[[x]][1,]=rep(100,ncol(li[[x]])))
```

the function lapply returns the list of vectors not desired matrices. The output of this function has the form:

```
> li.prim
[[1]]
[1] 100 100 100

[[2]]
[1] 100 100 100 100

[[3]]
[1] 100 100 100 100 100
```

My question is: how to perform the above operation on a list of matrices using the lapply or related function in r ?

Comment: You have to return the modified matrix from your unnamed function, `li.prim=lapply(1:3,function(x){li[[x]][1,]=rep(100,ncol(li[[x]])); li[[x]]})`.

Comment: Thanks for your aswer. This works very well !